# Value of n from combinatorial equation

Tags: combinations

Find the value of $n$ from the given equation:

$$\binom{n}{n}+2\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n-2} = \binom{n+2}{2n-3}$$

---

I have solved it to get the following and cannot proceed further:

$$\binom{n+2}{2} = \binom{n+2}{2n-3}\\
\frac{(n+2)!}{2!\cdot n!} = \frac{(n+2)!}{(2n-3)!(5-n)!}\\
 (2n-3)!(5-n)! = 2!\cdot n!$$

Comment: There are $0$ ways to choose $n$ elements from a set of $n-1$ elements. (Let alone $n-2$ elements!)

Comment: Wait, isn't $C^{n-1}_{n}=0?$

Comment: For clarification, by $C^r_n$ do you mean the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, the number of ways to choose $r$ objects out of $n$ objects total?

Comment: If the question is to be answered as it is, then $\binom{2n-3}{n+2}=\binom{n}{n}=1$, so $2n-3=n+2\implies n=5$.

Comment: In case this large amount of comments related to confusion about what your $C^r_n$ notation is meant to represent doesn't alarm you, it should.  I highly recommend getting away from any notation for binomial coefficients involving $C$ for the very reason that what some people denote as $\binom{n}{r}$ some people denote as $C^r_n$ while others denote as $C^n_r$ and it causes great confusion.  The $\binom{n}{r}$ notation is, as far as I know, completely unambiguous as to the meaning.

Comment: I got to the step: 2.n! = (2n-3)!(5-n)!

Comment: @HoàngQuỳnh The comments are asking for the definition of $C^a_b$ which you are using.

Comment: Can you show us the steps you've taken?

Comment: $\ $ $\ $ $\  $  $C_n^n$ +2$C_n^{n-1}$ + $C_n^{n-2}$ = $C_{n+2}^{2n-3}$ 

$\leftrightarrow$ $\ $ $C_{n+1}^n$ + $C_{n+1}^{n-1}$ = $C_{n+2}^{2n-3}$ 

$\leftrightarrow$ $\ $  $C_{n+2}^{n}$ = $C_{n+2}^{2n-3}$ 

$\leftrightarrow$ $\ $ $\frac{(n+2)!}{2.n!}$ = $\frac{(n+2)!}{(2n-3)!(5-n)!}$

$\leftrightarrow$ $\ $ 2.n! = (2n-3)!(5-n)!

Comment: Sorry, because my notation made you confused. I just learned to write like that in school, so I do not know about your notation.

Comment: @HoàngQuỳnh $\binom{n}{r} = C_{n}^{r}$

Comment: It mean : choose r in n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another rule (I forgot its name) which says that (for $n, a, b \in \Bbb N$) if:

$$\binom{n}{a} = \binom{n}{b}$$

then either $a = b$ or $n-a = b$.

Apply this rule to your answer $\binom{n+2}{2} = \binom{n+2}{2n-3}$ to get either  of the following equations:

1. $2n-3 = 2$ *or*
2. $2n-3 = n$

We reject first one because it gives fractional value for $n$. Only the second one gives valid answer which is $n = 3$.

---

Of course a smart way (as the smart Michael already posted) is to note that $n+2 \ge 2n-3$ giving $n \le 5$. Checking is very easy then.

Answer (score 1):

Just $2n-3\leq n+2$ and easy checking.

Comment: Why?  Isn’t  it = instead of <=

Comment: If we write $C_n^k$ or $\binom{n}{k}$ then $n\geq k$ by definition.

Comment: Is this assuming n is a nonnegative integer? (not any rational number or something weirder?)

Comment: But LHS is 1, since the 2 other terms are 0.  This means 2n-3=n+2 right?  Also, I don’t understand your comment because it is in mathjax

Comment: I think we say about combinatoric.

Comment: @XcoderX there is some discussion in the comments to the original post whether $C^a_b$ means $\binom ab$ or $\binom ba$. Michael Rozenberg is assuming the latter, because frankly, it is the most probable.

Comment: Oh okay Arthur, understand now

Comment: Heres +1 to the smart michael!